# how to assign admin functions to users

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a site where every club member is free to register& login but cannot chat/or view other members profile without being confirmed by the admin. We are only 5 in admin level but people joining are too much for us.
My question is; I need a code which will enable any confirmed member to confirm two members.

Simply put: code to make 1 approve 2&3. 2 will approve 4&5.3 will approve 5&6. That means turn by turn work. A kind of 2:1 matrix. Anyone who have approved someone can't approve again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

When the user is approved he should be granted 2 approvals - as he can approve anyone you need to subtract the number of people he can approve after he does that. It would be pretty simple to do as you just need one extra column in the users table in the database.

As for the code that depends entirely on your application and you did not specify any details of it.

Comment: @Master Greg, thank you for your concern and answer. I will post the codes I have for modifications. Let me gather them together.